# Running windows 7 emulator without the requirement for wddm 1.1

Tags: c#, .net, windows, windows-phone-7

I'm from the android background. I have installed .net and windows phone sdk.  When I tried to open the windows phone emulator it say's that :

> My computer doesn't have requried grahics unit processing . . . .

I have intel 945 graphics card. I tried for wddm 1.1. But it seems that I'm out of luck. I couldn't find any drivers.

Are there any way in which I can create windows app without the requirement for wddm 1.1?

This is really frustrating.

Comment: Well, you can still deploy your app on a real device. But is that a Silverlight or XNA app? XNA hardware requirements are more strict than Silverlight.

Comment: Its an Silverlight application.

Comment: @KooKiz: I can just compile and see whether my code at least runs without an error, before I try in physical device. Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Intel didn't provide WDDM 1.1 drivers for the 945 chipset.

If this is a desktop machine, you could always grab a mid/low-end $40 discrete graphics adaptor, most of which support WDDM 1.1 (e.g. http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814131398). If this is a laptop, look for a new device:

A (now, somewhat elderly) 945-era PC is not going to deliver a solid experience when running something as demanding as the Windows Phone 7 emulator. Note: The WP7 emulator is a full device emulator, not a simple simulator as offered on other mobile platforms' SDK's.

This is more the case when running the Windows Phone 8 SDK as its emulator runs on Hyper-V which requires a 64-bit CPU: http://www.wpcentral.com/windows-phone-8-emulator%E2%80%99s-hardware-requirements.

I strongly recommend aiming for a Nehalem-class PC (i.e. Core-i5/7 based PC) which has a processor that supports Second Level Address Translation (SLAT): This will prevent your CPU and GPU unnecessarily flushing the TLB and slowing down your PC: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tvoellm/archive/2009/04/06/why-does-my-desktop-box-slowdown-when-i-install-hyper-v.aspx.

HTH.